# Remove closest dynamic element within the same row using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple row which are dynamically generated i want to, there is a dropdown list i want to hide input fields next to dropdown of only row whose selection value is 2, i have tried below exampe but it is not working.

```js
$(document.body).on('change', '.check_valid', function() {
  if ($(this).children("option:selected").val() == 2) {
    $(this).closest(".form-control.text_min").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Classn</h5>
    <select name="input" class="form-control show-tick check_valid" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
      <option value="2">High School</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Min</h5>
    <div class="form-line focused">
      <input type="text" name="min[][]" placeholder="Min" class="form-control text_min">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h5 class="card-inside-title">Classn</h5>
      <select name="input" class="form-control show-tick check_valid" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
        <option value="2">High School</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h5 class="card-inside-title">Min</h5>
      <div class="form-line focused">
        <input type="text" name="min[][]" placeholder="Min" class="form-control text_min">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I believe jquery `.closest` goes **UP** the DOM tree ([ref](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) - _"The .parents() and .closest() methods are similar in that they both traverse up the DOM tree."_). Your `select` in relation to your `.form-control` is not up. Use `.closest` to find the parent `.row`, then once the row is found you can use `.find` to get the form control. ex: `var $row = $(this).closest('.row'); $row.find('.form-control');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate much further

```js
$(document).on('change', '.check_valid', function() {
  $(this).closest(".row").next().find(".text_min").toggle(this.value!=="2");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Classn</h5>
    <select name="input" class="form-control show-tick check_valid" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
      <option value="2">High School</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Min</h5>
    <div class="form-line focused">
      <input type="text" name="min[][]" placeholder="Min" class="form-control text_min">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h5 class="card-inside-title">Classn</h5>
      <select name="input" class="form-control show-tick check_valid" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
        <option value="2">High School</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h5 class="card-inside-title">Min</h5>
      <div class="form-line focused">
        <input type="text" name="min[][]" placeholder="Min" class="form-control text_min">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i select the second dropdown then its respective min fields does not hides,only first one is working